# Identify step direction in line search

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent

I have a function $f(x,y)$ which is continuous on both $x,y$ and want to find a local maximum. In my case, the gradient of $f$ is too difficult to derive.

Based on the idea of line search, I wonder if it is reasonable to identify the step direction by just comparing $f(x+\alpha,y),f(x+y),f(x-\alpha,y)$ (and do the same procedure on $y$) where $\alpha$ is small? For example, if $f(x_0+\alpha,y)>f(x_0+y)$, then $x_1=x_0+\alpha$. Is there any problem of this naive approach?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Are you sure the function is differentiable? If it is, you could use those values to estimate the partial derivatives, and hence the gradient. I'm not sure the best way to ensure that your estimates are close though. What is your function? If you are able to type it into a computer, are you sure the computer cannot compute the gradient?